# Opening a directory and then scanning parent directories for matching files

Tags: perl

```
    my $directory = shift @_;
    my @dh;
    my @files;

    opendir (my $dh, $directory) or die "Couldn't open dir '$directory' : $!";
    foreach my $file(readdir $dh) {
        if( -f $file =~ /\.htm$/){
                    push(@files,$file);
        }
        elsif(-d $file){
            push(@dh,$file);
            $dh = shift @dh;
        }

        closedir ($dh);
    }
```

I am trying to get my script to take in a path e.g. DATA/ (which is successful), however i want my script to scan through that directory and child directories and then if any file matches it will be stored in `@files`.

I am trying to use loop to scan through all subfolder e.g.

```
elsif(-d $file){
    push(@dh,$file);
    $dh = shift @dh;
}
```

In this statement `$dh` will get a new child directory name to scan through

However i am getting `Segmentation fault`

Comment: This is one of those things where you rely on already-written code. Use File::Find which is core Perl, or File::Next which installs easily via the CPAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

- `readdir` returns the pseudo-directories `.` and `..` and these should be ignored
- `readdir` returns only the file name and not the full path to the file. So `-f` and `-d` will look in the current working directory for an entry with this name and probably won't find it
- You are pushing directory names onto `@dh` but shifting directory handles `$dh` off it, which isn't going to work
- The test `-f $file =~ /\.htm$/` first applies the regex to the `$file` variable, and then uses the result of that (either `1` or `""`) as a parameter to `-f`. That isn't what you want at all
- You jump to processing a new directory as soon as you find one, so the rest of the current directory isn't going to be processed

Things like this are normally done using [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind) or a recursive subroutine, but you can do something like this by eliminiating tail recursion. **Note** that it takes no account of directory links and can loop endlessly if it finds one. This is why it is best to use a module which has all these kinks ironed out.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @dh = @_;
my @files;

while (@dh) {

  my $directory = shift @dh;
  opendir my $dh, $directory or die "Couldn't open dir '$directory' : $!";

  while (readdir $dh) {
    next if /\A\.\.?\z/;
    my $node= "$directory/$_";

    if (-f $node and /\.html?$/i) {
      push @files, $node;
    }
    elsif (-d $node) {
      push @dh, $node;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: would you mind explaining the code `next if /\A\.\.?\z/;
    my $node= "$directory/$_";` I am not very sure how this works :(

Comment: The regex `\A` matches the beginning of the string. `\.` matches a dot `\.?` matches an optional dot, and `\z` matches the end of the string. So the whole pattern matches a string containing exactly one or two dots. The assignment combines the current directory with the current file name with a slash in-between and puts the result into `$node`.